# Getting turrets to spawn

Tags: halo-combat-evolved

How can I make turrets spawn in Blood Gulch?

I've set both Red and Blue teams to 4 turrets in CTF, but none will spawn. I even reinstalled the game, still doesn't work.

Comment: Necro'd by a computer? WOW

Answer (score 1):

There are no stationary turrets on Blood Gulch, only those attached to the two Warthogs that spawn behind your team's base.

There is a mod to place turrets across the map called [Hog Turrets on Blood Gulch](http://www.fileplanet.com/136968/130000/fileinfo/Hog-Turrets-on-Blood-Gulch).  To install this mod, use a PPFA applier such as [PPF-O-Matic](http://www.romhacking.net/utilities/356/) and apply the patch to your `bloodgulch.map` file in the `MAPS` directory (default is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Halo\MAPS`).  Don't forget to make a backup of the original .map file before applying the mod.